# shell stderr to /dev/null

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I have PID file and I want to get PID number so this is what I am doing.

```
[root@linux ~]# PID=`cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid`
[root@linux ~]# echo $PID
3414
```

sometimes this file doesn't existing and this throwing file error, I want to specify to not throw an error, if file doesn't exist.

```
[root@linux ~]# PID=`cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid`
cat: /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to use `2&> /dev/null` but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `PID=$(cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: Quicky put your command in `ANSWER` i would like to give you +1 Vote... it works!!!

Comment: @cuonglm answer him dammit! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, start using `$()` for command substitution instead of older, problematic ``.

In you case, `cat` is showing error message when the file does not exist on the STDERR stream (file descriptor 2).

With command susbstution you are only saving what is on the STDOUT to the variable `PID`. So to get rid of the error message when the file does not exist, redirect the file descriptor 2 to `/dev/null`:

```
PID=$(cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid 2>/dev/null)
```

In `zsh` and `ksh` derivatives, you can use shortcut for `cat`:

```
PID=$(< /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid 2>/dev/null)
```

In `bash`, you can use `a=$(<file)` but not `a=$(<file 2>/dev/null)`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can check that a file exists before trying to read it by using the `test` aka `[` command:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid ]; then
    PID=$(cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid)
fi
```

or if you prefer one-liners:

```
[ -f /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid ] && PID=$(cat /usr/local/foo/var/run/foo.pid)
```

In a POSIX shell, using the `-f` option will return

> True if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a regular file. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a file that is not a regular file.

The `-r` test might be more appropriate as it also checks that the shell user actually has permission to *read* the file.

Comment: More complex way but still works for problem